# How to hack DataSource to use static data? (convert List<T> to DataSource<Int, T>)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have an UI component, that accepts `LiveData<PagedList<T>>` but in one case I need to use it for data passed directly from RecycleViewer (RecycleViewer produces outpus structured as `List<Object>`). I can easily map it to `Map<Int, Object>`, but Map cannot be cast to DataSource, so I need to somehow convert it either to `DataSource<Int, Object>` or directly to `<PagedList<Object>>`

I tried the below, but unfortunately it doesn't work -> error is that you cannot cast a MutableMap into DataSource. Any ideas?

```
class DataSourceFactory(
    val data: List<Object>
) : DataSourceFactory<Object>() {

   override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Object> {

        val mappedData = mutableMapOf<Int, Object>()
        var index = 0
        for (object in data) {
            mappedData[index] = object
            index = +1
        }
        return mappedData as DataSource<Int, Object>
    }
}
```

Comment: An embedded in-memory database, like H2 can deliver, is quite easy.

Comment: Could you be more specific? 
I'm passing to RecyclerViewer `List<Pair<String?, List<Object>>>` and RecyclerViewer is taking the pairData.first (which is `String?`) and displays it as title of the view and I need the pairData.second (which is `List<Object>`) to be passed to this UI component as `DataSource<Int, Object>`

Comment: Sorry forgot it is Android, not sufficient experience. Fortunately there already is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there, is no Object in Kotlin, you should use Any. You get an error because DataSource doesn't implement Map interface. If you don't want to add Map interface to DataSource, you can do something like this:

```
override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Any> {
    val dataSource = DataSource<Int, Any>()
    data.mapIndexed { index, any -> dataSource.put(index, any) }
    return dataSource
}
```

Just adapt method to add elements to DataSource - I used put in this example